# "certificate file does not exist" error when using charles web debugging proxy

Tags: proxy, ssl-certificate, charles-proxy

I have Installed charles and installed the charles CA SSL certificates as per help menu, with success confirmation.
BUt as I try to open any url with charles running, I am continuously getting an pop-up error 
of "certificate file does not exist".

Can some one please help me on how do I workaround the issue and still work with charles successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.  It's not related to your CA cert, it's a different thing, related to your client certs.

In charles, go to the Proxy menu and choose "Client SSL Certificates"

For some reason I had a mapping from *.* to blank/nothing.  Maybe you do too.  If so, remove all your mappings here and it will probably fix it.

Comment: Please, remove all items from Client SSL Certificates, no more this issue will appear

Answer (score 0):

WINDOWS / INTERNET EXPLORER

In Charles go to the Help menu and choose "Install Charles CA SSL Certificate". A window will appear warning you that the CA Root certificate is not trusted.

Click the "Install Certificate" button to launch the Certificate Import Wizard. The certificate must be imported into the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" certificate store, so override the automatic certificate store selection.

You will be asked to confirm the certificate thumbprint, it should read:
189B6E28 D1635F3A 8325E1E0 02180DBA 2C02C241

Complete the wizard and the CA SSL certificate is now installed. You may need to restart IE before the installation takes affect.

Answer (score 0):

(Windows) Since no one has said what fixed this for me-

After I followed along installing for windows I was getting this error. Make sure in the Proxy Settings under the SSL tab that use a custom CA certificate is NOT checked. Mine was, and this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. The problem was under Client Certs and it mapped * to where the C:\Downloads\charles.msi for some reason. Removed that and it was all good.